# How can I improve the bluetooth transfer rate with Glass XE12?

Tags: bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an Android app for Google Glass that communicates with an external device using Bluetooth. The device sends a short command and receives an acknowledgement. There were no perceptible delays when I used Glass XE11, but I noticed significant delays once I upgraded to XE12. Digging deeper, I found that the round trip for the command is in the order of 80 ms on an Android phone and 250-500 ms on Glass XE12. The code that I use is based on the BluetoothChat sample code.

Were there any changes to the way Google Glass handles Bluetooth communication between XE11 and XE12 that could explain these delays? Do you have any suggestions to reduce the delays? Thanks in advance!